# wpf Transparent window / layer with hotspots dependent on controls in child window

Tags: c#, wpf, transparent, layer

I am working on a WPF application and want to create a context sensitive help system. I want the help contents to be in an xml file that includes the current window name, controls and associated help with that control. This help screen would then open up with a transparent look to and it read from the xml file, then place help icons on this transparent window near the controls in the screen it is covering up, then when clicking a help icon it would display some help in a tooltip or something similar for the underlying control.

Any suggestions on creating a transparent window and having this window be able to find the location of certain controls in the window it is covering up?

Thanks for any input or ideas

Comment: Have you looked into WPF's Adorner support?  You may have better luck placing the icons in an AdornerLayer than a separate window, and it would certainly be easier to position them.

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, you can make a control transparent by setting its `Background` property to `Transparent`. You can use any control to display your help details and as long as it is declared at the bottom of your XAML, it will appear on top of the other controls. You might prefer to explicitly set the `Panel.ZIndex` property to increase its 'Z' order.

As for positioning this control, I assume that the positions will have something to do with the position of the mouse pointer. In this case, you could do something like this:

```
HitTestResult hitTestResult = 
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(adornedUIElement, e.GetPosition(adornedUIElement));
Control controlUnderMouse = hitTestResult.VisualHit.GetParentOfType<Control>();
```

...

```
public static T GetParentOfType<T>(this DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (element == null) return null;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    if (parent == null && ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent is DependencyObject) parent = ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent;
    if (parent == null) return null;
    else if (parent.GetType() == type || parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type)) return parent as T;
    return GetParentOfType<T>(parent);
}
```

This `GetParentOfType` method is an [Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx) and should be added into a `static` class.